# how to find column usage statistics in SQL server for non-indexed columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, teradata

I want to check how many users did a read or scan on particular column in a table. Is there any sql query I can write in SQL Server or Teradata to do that?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server has index usage DMV's. It does not show specific users, but it shows usage (seeks, scans, lookups, updates)

Comment: thanks. But, what about non-indexed columns. How can i find out usage info of perticular column which dont have index?

Comment: You will probably have to make a few assumptions here and there. You can query all your objects, get a list of every column within them (sql_referenced_entities and sql_referencing_entities), bump that up against a list of all columns that you have indexes on (sys.indexes and sys.index_columns), and see where the gaps are. You can also find PK's that have very high lookup counts. That means you are performing key lookups on the PK instead of seeks/scans on your NC indexes.

Comment: Or go hunting for key lookups in your plan cache (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-key-lookups-inside-the-plan-cache/), find what columns the lookup is happening for, and then index those.

Comment: When *Query Logging with Objects* is enabled you can find info about tables/columns used in a query in `dbc.QryLogObjectsV`

Comment: dbc.QryLogObjectsV seems like a option, but can be expensive. i will check and will let u know.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample SELECT statement retrieves the object information of a query:

```
SELECT QueryID, ObjectDatabaseName (Named ObjDBName), ObjectTableName (Named ObjTblName), ObjectColumnName (Named ObjColName), ObjectID (Named ObjId), ObjectNum (Named ObjNum), ObjectType (Named ObjType), FreqofUse
FROM DBC.QryLogObjectsV where queryid = 201205134619838031;
```

I referred it from [here](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035-1092-160K/fus1472240676534.html)